# How do I create a simple checkbox in a content entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I just want a boolean checkbox with a label beside it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use type `boolean_checkbox` and `display_label`:

```
$fields[$open] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
    ->setLabel(t("My Checkbox Field"))
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
      'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
      'settings' => array(
        'display_label' => TRUE,
      ),
      'weight' => '0',
    ))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Comment: class BaseFieldDefinition namespace is `Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition`

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked. Not sure if it's the best approach though:

```
  $fields[$open] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
    ->setLabel(t("My Checkbox Field"))
    ->setSetting('on_label', t("Label that actually shows up on the form"))
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
      'type' => 'boolean',
      'weight' => '0',
    ))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: Can we expand on this as to why a field wasn't created?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The issue I was encountering is that the label wasn't working - it would always just display 'on' beside the box. Using the special 'on_label' setting worked, but I'm confused why it's set up that way

Comment: if you switch off, you get the default label 'off'

Answer (score 0):

D8 ... Add field > select field type Boolean and give it a label > save and continue > Save settings again ... go to Manage Display and select the options icon to the right of the field you just added > under Output form dropdown you will have many selections, i.e., On/Off, Yes/No, True/False, Enable/Disable, 1/0, etc.
Then go to Manage form display, next to the filed you just added under Widget select Single on/off checkbox.

Comment: Would that work with a content entity?

Comment: I created the checkbox/radio buttons in a Content Type via the Manage Display tab. My understanding is Content Types use content entities. Views are configuration entities.